# Vyos VPN from AWS to Cisco

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, vyos

I'm trying to configure Vyos VPN from AWS VPC to Cisco VPN.

I'm using prepared AWS AIM images - tried vyos 1.1.7 and vyos 1.2.

My Vyos instance is in a public segment of VPC:

```
vyos@ip-10-0-2-238:~$ show interfaces
Codes: S - State, L - Link, u - Up, D - Down, A - Admin Down
Interface        IP Address                        S/L  Description
---------        ----------                        ---  -----------
eth0             10.0.2.238/24                     u/u
lo               127.0.0.1/8                       u/u
             ::1/128
```

It also has external IP.

My configuration is:

```
interfaces {
    ethernet eth0 {
        address dhcp
    }
    loopback lo {
    }
}
....
interfaces {
    ethernet eth0 {
        address dhcp
    }
    loopback lo {
    }
}

vpn {
    ipsec {
        esp-group test-esp {
            compression disable
            lifetime 7200
            mode tunnel
            pfs enable
            proposal 1 {
                encryption aes256
                hash sha256
            }
        }
        ike-group test-ike {
            ikev2-reauth no
            key-exchange ikev2
            lifetime 28800
            proposal 1 {
                dh-group 2
                encryption aes256
                hash sha256
            }
        }
        ipsec-interfaces {
            interface eth0
        }
        site-to-site {
            peer IP_OF_REMOTE_CISCO {
                authentication {
                    id MY_REMOTE_IP
                    mode pre-shared-secret
                    pre-shared-secret ****************
                }
                connection-type initiate
                ike-group test-ike
                ikev2-reauth inherit
                local-address LOCAL_IP_OF_VYOS_INSTANCE
                tunnel 1 {
                    allow-nat-networks disable
                    allow-public-networks disable
                    esp-group test-esp
                    local {
                        prefix MY_MASK_OF_PRIVATE_SUBNET
                    }
                    remote {
                        prefix LOCAL_SUBNET_BEHIND_VPN
                    }
                }
           }
```

VPN connection remains in status "CONNECTING":

```
peer-X.X.X.X-tunnel-1[1]: CONNECTING, Y.Y.Y.Y[%any]...X.X.X.X[%any]
peer-X.X.X.X-tunnel-1[1]: IKEv2 SPIs: 6911b8b8bf6ad261_i* 0000000000000000_r
peer-X.X.X.X-tunnel-1[1]: Tasks active: IKE_VENDOR IKE_INIT IKE_NATD IKE_CERT_PRE IKE_AUTH IKE_CERT_POST IKE_CONFIG CHILD_CREATE IKE_AUTH_LIFETIME IKE_MOBIKE
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: logs !! what do the Cisco says ? does he receive some packets at least ?

Comment: which logs and where can I see on vyos side?